# laravel eloquent order by multiple columns and show in one column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 4 tables:

- user
- particular
- pro
- advertiser

I have a table where i show the users data.
in this table i have a column named Name where i use the code below

```
                       <td>
                            @if($user->pro))
                                {{$user->pro->company_name}}
                            @elseif($user->particular))
                                {{$user->particular->name." ".$user->particular->last_name}}
                            @elseif($user->advertiser)
                                {{$user->advertiser->company_name}}
                            @endif
                        </td>
```

So this column is popuplated from 3 different tables and different column.
How can i sort this column table.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need a complex ORDER BY clause that you won't be able to set up using Eloquent's methods. However, Eloquent builder offers *orderByRaw()* method that let's you use raw SQL expression in your ORDER BY clause. Combine that with a couple of SQL IF's (for MySQL see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) and you should get what you need.

In your case it would be sth like:

```
->orderByRaw("IF(user.is_pro,pro.company_name,IF(user.is_particular, particular.name, IF(user.is_advertiser,advertiser.company_name,'')))")
```

Keep in mind that ordering by such expressions might have negative performance impact and that using raw SQL might make your code less portable.